Java KeyPress is getting the value before the key press, not the value during the key press
I'm writing a Java program that generates 5 random letters when user press G. After pressing G, if user press S, the next pressed key would be compared to the random generated letters to check if it matches with that key.
Here's my code:
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class randomFive{
        private static JFrame frame;
        private static JLabel num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
        private static char n1;
        
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Create a JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add or Subtract");
        
        // Set the layout manager to null
        frame.setLayout(null);
        // Set the size of the frame
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        // Set default close operation
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set the frame visibility
        frame.setVisible(true);

        n1 = 'a';

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            boolean gPressed = false; // Flag to track if 'G' is pressed
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G) {
                    gPressed = true; // Set the flag to true if 'G' is pressed
                    if (num1 != null) {
                        frame.remove(num1);
                        frame.remove(num2);
                        frame.remove(num3);
                        frame.remove(num4);
                        frame.remove(num5);
                    }

                    //generate random letters from a to z
                    Random r = new Random();
                    n1 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n2 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n3 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n4 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n5 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

                    // Create new JLabel components
                    num1 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n1));
                    num2 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n2));
                    num3 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n3));
                    num4 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n4));
                    num5 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n5));

                    // Set the size and position of components
                    num1.setBounds(140, 200, 200, 20);
                    num2.setBounds(170, 200, 200, 20);
                    num3.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 20);
                    num4.setBounds(230, 200, 200, 20);
                    num5.setBounds(260, 200, 200, 20);

                    // Add JLabel components to the frame
                    frame.add(num1);
                    frame.add(num2);
                    frame.add(num3);
                    frame.add(num4);
                    frame.add(num5);

                    // Repaint the frame to reflect the changes
                    frame.repaint();
                    
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && gPressed) {
                    // Check if 'S' is pressed after 'G'
                    System.out.println("'S' key is pressed after 'G'");
                    char keyPressed = e.getKeyChar(); // Get the character of the key pressed
                    System.out.println("keyPress value is: " + keyPressed);
                    System.out.println("n1 value is: " + n1);

                    // Convert the string to char and compare with n1
                    if (keyPressed == n1) {
                        // Compare the first character of the string with n1
                        System.out.println("The pressed key matches n1");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        // Set the frame to focusable so that it can receive key events
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        // Request the focus for the frame so that it can start receiving key events
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();

    }
}

But focus on this code block, this is where the problem happens:
else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && gPressed) {
                    // Check if 'S' is pressed after 'G'
                    System.out.println("'S' key is pressed after 'G'");
                    char keyPressed = e.getKeyChar(); // Get the character of the key pressed
                    System.out.println("keyPress value is: " + keyPressed);
                    System.out.println("n1 value is: " + n1);

                    // Convert the string to char and compare with n1
                    if (keyPressed == n1) {
                        // Compare the first character of the string with n1
                        System.out.println("The pressed key matches n1");
                    }
                }

When I run the code, let's say the value of n1 is "a", the value of keyPressed is always S even though I pressed a. And I set the value of keyPressed inside the else if block so it should get the current pressed key, not the previously pressed S key. What should I do?

n1 is only set once, when the numbers are generated and not changed thereafter. Avoid null layouts in Swing
Also, use key bindings, not key listeners

char keyPressed = e.getKeyChar(); is redundant as the handler knows that has to be 's'. n1 will still have the same value as when first generated

According to how I understand your description of how your Swing application is supposed to work, the user needs to press three keys. After pressing G, five, random, lowercase letters of the English alphabet are displayed. After that, once the user presses S, [s]he then needs to press a third letter on the computer keyboard after which you check whether the third keypress matches the first of the five displayed letters.
In other words, your check needs to be after the third keypress, however according to your code you are checking it after the second keypress. The else-if block is only executed if the user presses S after [s]he has pressed G.
What you need is another else-if that is executed after the user has pressed G followed by S.
In the below code, I added a sPressed flag and the extra else-if is executed when both gPressed and sPressed are true.
I suggest that you copy the below code as is, i.e. without changing any of it, compile it, run it and see if it does what you want.
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomFive {
    private static JLabel num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    private static char n1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add or Subtract");

        // Set the layout manager to null
        frame.setLayout(null);
        // Set the size of the frame
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        // Set default close operation
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set the frame visibility
        frame.setVisible(true);

        n1 = 'a';

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            boolean gPressed = false; // Flag to track if 'G' is pressed
            boolean sPressed = false; // Flag to track if 'S' is pressed

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G) {
                    gPressed = true; // Set the flag to true if 'G' is pressed
                    if (num1 != null) {
                        frame.remove(num1);
                        frame.remove(num2);
                        frame.remove(num3);
                        frame.remove(num4);
                        frame.remove(num5);
                    }

                    // generate random letters from a to z
                    Random r = new Random();
                    n1 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n2 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n3 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n4 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    char n5 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

                    // Create new JLabel components
                    num1 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n1));
                    num2 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n2));
                    num3 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n3));
                    num4 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n4));
                    num5 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(n5));

                    // Set the size and position of components
                    num1.setBounds(140, 200, 200, 20);
                    num2.setBounds(170, 200, 200, 20);
                    num3.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 20);
                    num4.setBounds(230, 200, 200, 20);
                    num5.setBounds(260, 200, 200, 20);

                    // Add JLabel components to the frame
                    frame.add(num1);
                    frame.add(num2);
                    frame.add(num3);
                    frame.add(num4);
                    frame.add(num5);

                    // Repaint the frame to reflect the changes
                    frame.repaint();

                }
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && gPressed) {
                    sPressed = true;
                    // Check if 'S' is pressed after 'G'
                    System.out.println("'S' key is pressed after 'G'");
                }
                else if (gPressed && sPressed) {
                    gPressed = false;
                    sPressed = false;
                    char keyPressed = e.getKeyChar(); // Get the character of the key pressed
                    System.out.println("keyPress value is: " + keyPressed);
                    System.out.println("n1 value is: " + n1);

                    // Convert the string to char and compare with n1
                    if (keyPressed == n1) {
                        // Compare the first character of the string with n1
                        System.out.println("The pressed key matches n1");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Set the frame to focusable so that it can receive key events
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        // Request the focus for the frame so that it can start receiving key events
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}


not working. i shouldn't be able to press g again when s is pressed

i shouldn't be able to press g again when s is pressed Pardon me, but I did not see that requirement in your question. What did I miss?
